# Error handling for http.get request in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    http.get('http://nodejs.org/dist/index.json', (res) => {
        response.write("Inside http");
        response.end();
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
});
server.listen(3000);
```

On running above code, neither control goes inside `http.get` nor it throws any error.What am I missing here in catching the error?

Note : Server is created at 3000

Comment: When asking for help, please break your code into reasonable lines and format and indent your code reasonably (this is a good idea when *not* asking for help, too). (Alon Eitan and I have fixed it for you on this occasion.)

Comment: I tried formatting your code but I will not add line breaks, please [edit] your post and format the code correctly to make it more readable

Comment: Oh, T.J just did it for you :)

Comment: Thanks Alon & T.J for taking care of format.Will keep the same in mind for future

Answer (score 2):

add application level error handler in you app. If anything goes wrong, it will catch the error

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  // This should not happen
  logger.error("Pheew ....! Something unexpected happened. This should be handled more gracefully. I am sorry. The culprit is: ", err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems http.get should be placed in following way for it to work properly:

```
var http = require('http');
console.log('Before server');
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.log('Request received');
});
server.listen(3000, function() {
  http.get('http://nodejs.org/dist/index.json', (res) => {
    console.log('Inside http');
  })
  .on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
  });
});
```